# Cannot resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06 because no repositories are defined. Required by:     project :app

Comment: It's recommended not to use alpha dependencies

Comment: Do you have jcenter in gradle? `repositories {
       jcenter()
    }`

Comment: can you suggest me the recommended dependency

Comment: @arjunds `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` maybe?

Comment: ya i already have a repositories { jcenter() } in my gradle

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'   this did not work for me

Comment: any other solutions. please let me know.

Comment: Please add both your gradle files to the question to show a [mcve]

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i was able to resolve it by changing the  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'                                                                                classpath  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06'
And adding- distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip in gradle properties along with adding the {jcenter()}. Thank each one of you for your valuable inputs to help me resolve the issue.